# Recordset via a variable

Tags: sql, recordset

I have a recordset which works fine but needs some tweaking.

This is what I have:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.profiles
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.self_assess
        ON dbo.profiles.profile_id = dbo.self_assess.self_assess_profile_id
            And dbo.self_assess.sa_year = 3
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.lesson_observation
        ON dbo.profiles.profile_id = dbo.lesson_observation.lesson_obsv_profile_id
            And dbo.lesson_observation.lo_year = 3
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.staffappraisal_head_dept
        ON dbo.profiles.profile_id = dbo.staffappraisal_head_dept.sa_hd_profile_id
            And dbo.staffappraisal_head_dept.sahd_year = 3
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.staffappraisal_main_meeting
        ON dbo.profiles.profile_id = dbo.staffappraisal_main_meeting.sa_mainappraisal_teacherid
            And dbo.staffappraisal_main_meeting.samm_year = 3
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup
        ON dbo.profiles.profile_id = dbo.staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup.sa_ma_fup_teachers_id
            And dbo.staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup.samafu_year = 3
WHERE
    lesson_obsv_by_id = VarLesson
    OR sa_hd_hod_id = VarHod
    OR sa_mainappraisal_appraiser_id = VarMainApp
    OR sa_ma_fup_appraiser_id = VarMainFollow
    OR self_assess_hod_id = VarSelf
    AND lo_year = varyear1
    AND sa_year = varyear2
    AND sahd_year = varyear3
    AND samm_year = varyear4
    AND samafu_year = varyear5
```

---

what i would like is to have the ( 3)

```
dbo.lesson_observation.lo_year = 3
```

to equal to a variable which could be called `ACTIVEYEAR`

Regards

Vitor

Comment: . . Have you heard of table aliases?  They would really help you write code that is easier to write and to read.

Comment: Seems like [using a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in sql server is pretty straight forward. Specificall the [first example on that page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If that's not what you had in mind, please update your question with more information.

Comment: HI There, Gordon and jnevill, thanks for sorting the table. I am just a starter on this so not as hot as you guys ;-), isnt there an easier way than the example?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
DECLARE @ActiveYear INT = 3

SELECT
    *
FROM
    dbo.profiles
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.self_assess
        ON dbo.profiles.profile_id = dbo.self_assess.self_assess_profile_id
            And dbo.self_assess.sa_year = @ActiveYear
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.lesson_observation
        ON dbo.profiles.profile_id = dbo.lesson_observation.lesson_obsv_profile_id
            And dbo.lesson_observation.lo_year = @ActiveYear
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.staffappraisal_head_dept
        ON dbo.profiles.profile_id = dbo.staffappraisal_head_dept.sa_hd_profile_id
            And dbo.staffappraisal_head_dept.sahd_year = @ActiveYear
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.staffappraisal_main_meeting
        ON dbo.profiles.profile_id = dbo.staffappraisal_main_meeting.sa_mainappraisal_teacherid
            And dbo.staffappraisal_main_meeting.samm_year = @ActiveYear
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup
        ON dbo.profiles.profile_id = dbo.staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup.sa_ma_fup_teachers_id
            And dbo.staffappraisal_mainapprs_followup.samafu_year = @ActiveYear
WHERE
    lesson_obsv_by_id = VarLesson
    OR sa_hd_hod_id = VarHod
    OR sa_mainappraisal_appraiser_id = VarMainApp
    OR sa_ma_fup_appraiser_id = VarMainFollow
    OR self_assess_hod_id = VarSelf
    AND lo_year = varyear1
    AND sa_year = varyear2
    AND sahd_year = varyear3
    AND samm_year = varyear4
    AND samafu_year = varyear5
```

Comment: Yes! but it does not work.
 this is the error!
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0408'

Invalid character

/test-list.asp, line 10

DECLARE @ActiveYear INT = 3
--------^

Comment: Basically what i would like to have, to have the numbers replaced by a variable which comes from a query string called active year., thanks in advance

Comment: VBScript?  Your tag stated this was SQL

Comment: sorry for not answering, thank you for all your help, i am away and as soon i am back will try it. Again thank you so much for your help